# Postgres: More verbose error message: I am missing the table name

Tags: postgresql

I see this message:

```
IntegrityError: null value in column "date" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (10005, null, f, TEST, MAIL).
```

Is there a way to get a more verbose error message from PostgreSQL?

I am missing the table name.

Comment: you can see the model for which you are creating or updating the data. The table will be created in Django with the combination of app name and model name and ofcourse we can change it by overriding db_table in the meta data of the model.

Comment: @MicroPyramid I think it my mistake to talk about "django" here. I want a better error message from postgres.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`psql` can do that using the `VERBOSITY` option:

```
psql (9.6.1)
Type "help" for help.

postgres> \set VERBOSITY verbose
postgres> insert into foobar (data) values ('x');
ERROR:  23502: null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (null, x).
SCHEMA NAME:  public
TABLE NAME:  foobar
COLUMN NAME:  id
LOCATION:  ExecConstraints, execMain.c:1732
postgres>
```

This was introduced in 9.6. However, I don't know how this can be used from other clients.

Alternatively this can be obtained without setting `VERBOSITY` by using the meta command `\errverbose`

```
postgres> insert into foobar (data) values ('x');
ERROR:  null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (null, x).

postgres> \errverbose
ERROR:  23502: null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (null, x).
SCHEMA NAME:  public
TABLE NAME:  foobar
COLUMN NAME:  id
LOCATION:  ExecConstraints, execMain.c:1732

postgres>
```

This is apparently implemented on libpq level so it could theoretically be used from any program.

Comment: Yes, it is part of `PQresultErrorField()` For instance:  https://github.com/JamesSjaalman/gigabert/blob/master/pgstuff.c (see under "extra:")

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I looked for something like this several months ago. Now it is available. Great news. Thank you.

Comment: Here is the follow up question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41996182/how-to-turn-on-postgresql-verbosity-in-django-db-connection "How to turn on PostgreSQL VERBOSITY in django db connection?"

Comment: Is possible to get this details inside a PostgreSQL function?

Answer (score 3):

When using `psql`:

`\errverbose` Reports the most recent error message in detail.

`\set VERBOSITY verbose` Shows the most context for any error reports for the current session or when the setting is revised down to `default`, `terse`, or `sqlstate`.

If running SQL scripts or batches of commands, a way to show context of an ERROR with `psql` is to use the `--echo-errors` option. The option prints failed SQL commands to standard error output.

If your sending a script to `psql` using the `-f` option shows the line number of the error.