# How to turn on PostgreSQL VERBOSITY in django db connection?

Tags: django, postgresql

This is a follow up question to this:

[Postgres: More verbose error message: I am missing the table name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41959752/postgres-more-verbose-error-message-i-am-missing-the-table-name)

PostgreSQL 9.6 improved error messages with version 9.6.

With `psql` you can enable it `\set VERBOSITY verbose`.

How to enable this for every connection inside django ORM?

Background: I want better error messages.

Example: I am missing the table name in messages like this

```
IntegrityError: null value in column "date" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (10005, null, f, TEST, MAIL).
```

I think the relevant part of the [9.6 release notes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/release-9-6.html#AEN131275) is this:

> Add support in libpq for regenerating an error message with a different verbosity level (Alex Shulgin)
>
> This is done with the new function PQresultVerboseErrorMessage(). This supports psql's new \errverbose feature, and may be useful for other clients as well.

I use psycopg2 as database adapter.

Comment: you are working with psycopg2 between django and postgresql.  Thus those features should be transcluded by psycopg2  first. As I can see from docs - psycopg2 doesn't provides this neither in main code base nor in extras. :(

Comment: for server-side features you can always right after starting the transaction execute `SET client_min_messages  DEBUG5;`

Comment: @IlyaDyoshin I guess "\set VERBOSITY verbose" and "client_min_messages DEBUG5;" are different, or am I wrong?

Comment: yes those are not different. Thus \set VERBOSITY verbose is pure libpq and psql functionality, which have to be reflected in wrappers like psycopg2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
# settings.py
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': '...',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'init_command': "SET log_error_verbosity TO 'verbose'",
        },
    }
}
```

Test query

```
SELECT setting FROM pg_settings WHERE name = 'log_error_verbosity'
```

Comment: this is for mysql but how can i do the same for prostgres?

Comment: This is for PostgreSQL https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/runtime-config-logging.html#GUC-LOG-ERROR-VERBOSITY

Comment: i mean, Django has init_command only when it uses MySQL, init_command is not avaible for postgres https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/databases/#connecting-to-the-database i got this error: psycopg2.ProgrammingError: invalid dsn: invalid connection option "init_command" because that command is not for postgres

Comment: Seems this is not possible via configuration options. You can try to create `django.db.backends.signals`. Example https://gist.github.com/ketanbhatt/730b86ebece1aa91ebbf2b6182163bb8#file-models-py