# How turn on message errors?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I was "playing" with functions that I found on the internet with RAISE commands
and I don't know how, when and where I changed something and pgAdmin3 doesn't show me errors messages.

Now, when I run a wrong code, I get **ONLY** this message (for example):

```
Total query runtime: 12 msec
1 row returned
```

I would like to get an error message normally... Please, help..

Comment: Show us your code

Comment: The problem is that I can't find the code I found on the internet earlier. I didn't save it. I remember setting up something like that \set VERBOSITY terse

Comment: Could this be a problem? How to restore it?

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/runtime-config-logging.html Would that help? Or this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41996182/how-to-turn-on-postgresql-verbosity-in-django-db-connection Or just this "\set VERBOSITY verbose"

Comment: I've looked at it before but I don't know how to use it? 
I don't understand what is written there.

Comment: Well to get error codes on PG admin you could set ur verbocity to vebose. "\set VERBOSITY verbose"

Comment: @Comirdc Thank you so much!! It helped! :):)